# Opencv_traincascade- is it not possible to train opcncv_traincascade with just 26 samples or less?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, cascade, haar-classifier

I am trying to run this code in terminal

```
C:\Ankit\VirEnv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data cascade/ -vec C:\Ankit\VirEnv\pos3.vec -bg neg.txt -w 24 -h 24 -negPos 20 -numNeg 1000 -minHitRate 0.9
```

This is my output

```
(env) PS C:\Ankit\VirEnv> C:\Ankit\VirEnv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data cascade/ -vec C:\Ankit\VirEnv\pos3.vec -bg neg.txt -w 24 -h 24 -negPos 20 -numNeg 1000 -minHitRate 0.9
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: cascade/
vecFileName: C:\Ankit\VirEnv\pos3.vec
bgFileName: neg.txt
numPos: 2000
numNeg: 1000
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 24
sampleHeight: 24
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.9
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC
Number of unique features given windowSize [24,24] : 162336

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(3.4.16) Error: Bad argument (> Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.
> ) in CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::get, file C:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\apps\traincascade\imagestorage.cpp, line 158
```

I am getting this error

```
OpenCV(3.4.16) Error: Bad argument (> Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.
> ) in CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::get, file C:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\apps\traincascade\imagestorage.cpp, line 158
```

I only have 26 sample, I have tried to mess with Pog value and the minHitRate vale but still this error is there, i don't know what to do next. Is it not possible to do this with just 26 sample? is it necessary to have more than 26 sample to make this work.

Comment: minHitRate: 0.9 means you will lose up to 10% of your positive sample in each stage. numPos: 2000 is much too big if you only have 26 samples. Try minHitRate: 0.95 and numPos: 20 maybe. You should see a training running but that's really low amount of data...

Comment: if I make numPos equal to 26 or less than I get error such as 'POS count : consumed   26 : 26
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.'

Comment: can you show the full terminal output? Did it train a single stage and fail afterwards? What kind of negative samples do you use? Did you also try numPos: 20 so that there are a few unused samples left for the next stages?

Comment: the output error is something like this `PS C:\Ankit\VirEnv> C:\Ankit\VirEnv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data cascade/ -vec C:\Ankit\VirEnv\pos3.vec -bg neg.txt -w 24 -h 24 -negPos 27 -numPos 2 -numNeg 1000 -minHitRate 0.95 .
===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   15 : 15
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.`

Comment: I guess is because if the low samples? is there a threshold of some exact number the sample should be?

Comment: I dont know whether there is a lower bound. During runtime, does the "can not be filled" message appear immediately after the "pos count" appears or is there a neg counter increasing until it finally fails? What kind of negative samples do you use during training (amount, resolution, etc.)?

Comment: yes the message occurs right after pos count. There is 18 negative sample and 26 positive sample.  resolution is 640*780 same for both negative and positive image.